# Give another name for column in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I'm integrating 1 script as backend for another. Both the scripts uses PHP/Mysql. There is however one catch as in the "Users" table the frontend uses "id" for the user's id & the backend uses "uid".

Is there any way to give two names for the same column so that the modding can be done easily ?

Answer (score 3):

Just use an alias:

```
SELECT
  id,
  id AS uid
FROM
  tablename;
```

Answer (score 1):

[View](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html) can help you